# What does this exchange about a handkerchief and a sleeve mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, my-fair-lady

In *My Fair Lady* the following dialogue ocurs:

> **ELIZA**: What's this for?
>
> **HIGGINS**: To wipe your eyes. To wipe any part of your face that feels moist.
>
> Remember, that's your handkerchief and that's your sleeve.
>
> Don't confuse one with the other, if you want to become a lady in a
>   shop.

What does it mean?

Comment: Looking into the dictionary what a "handkerchief" is and what a "sleeve" is would be a start, I guess.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To summarise [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Fair_Lady), the story of *My Fair Lady* is as follows:

> The story concerns Eliza Doolittle, a Cockney flower girl who takes
>   speech lessons from professor Henry Higgins, a phoneticist, so that
>   she may pass as a lady.

In other words, taking a *common girl* and making her into *a proper lady*.

The lines you refer to are the professor telling her that ***a proper lady would wipe her face with a handkerchief, not her sleeve***. Only a *common* girl would use her sleeve. Thus, if she used her sleeve it would give away that she was from a common background - which would be bad, since Henry wants her to pass as a lady.